# Erratic reputation score movement?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, reputation

Earlier in the day 27/02/2011, my reputation was 3445 and as of evening 27/02/2011 the same has reduced to 3408.

I checked out my reputation graph and there shows no down votes either.

Anyone's got an idea how to track what is going on?

Comment: Phew... I was worried there for a little bit. Wish it showed up on the graph as some annotation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There was a rep recalculation performed on your account. It would've removed rep from questions and answers that were deleted or migrated to another site.

It was a StackExchange-wide recalc done as part of the preparations for the new Users page. More details [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80862/sudden-sharp-drop-in-reputation-find-out-reason-recalc) on Meta.SO.

Comment: Even if the recalculation was a good idea, that's a shame because personally, I delete my own answers if they are not selected when the selected answer is very similar, in order to keep threads clean of duplicates, so it could be interesting to add an exception to the rule when the answer is deleted by its author.

Comment: @wildpeaks Thank you for doing your part to keep the threads clean of duplicates. :) That said, I don't think that deserves to be an exception, honestly. Why the answer is deleted is not important in terms of rep calculation -- especially because while you delete your answers for noble reasons that is not the case for everybody else.

Answer (score 1):

See [Sudden sharp reputation drop problem: points disappeared and score lost (recalc?)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80862/sudden-sharp-drop-in-reputation-find-out-reason-recalc) for the details.  This was StackExchange wide in preparation for some upcoming changes.